# Icon to show amount of posts on a blog

Tags: icon, blog

Cant think of any ideas for this.

Currently im using a pencil icon to add a new post to my cms, but i need an icon that will show how many posts a blog has.

The pencil icon doesnt scale down well enough for what im doing.

Any other suggestions?

Craig.

e.g.

[image: example]

The icon currently being used:

[image: small pencil]

Answer (score 1):

If your blog is tailored to vehicles get creative maybe use a vehicle:

[image]

from [Iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/254116/car_police_taxi_traffic_icon#size=128)

Could use a street sign:

[image]

from [Iconfinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/117490/bicycle_construction_learning_motorbike_sign_sport_street_traffic_traffic_light_training_transport_transportation_icon#size=128)

Personally when it comes to designing blogs and icons I try to create a custom set designed for that site because I find it adds a better quality to the site.  Some could argue that it may be harder to understand what the icon may mean because some icons just have a global understanding to them.

If that doesn't work some people I've seen use:

[image]

[Source](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/211177/location_map_marker_pin_point_reminder_sticky_tack_icon#size=128)

or:

[image]

The above would probably be better in a silhouette.

Comment: Excellent reply! thanks. Am scrolling through my icons now trying to find something unique. Looks like the note icon is the best currently. Ill use it as a placeholder.

Comment: @Craig no problem and welcome to GD.  If you find an answer does in fact answer your question please make sure to mark it as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking "Blog"....

- A Megaphone
- A Radio
- A Billboard
- A Document
- A Post-It
- A Newspaper